# using CLR interfaces with F# types

Tags: c#, f#, clr, interface

im having a bit of problems using any decent C# interface with my F# types
so given i have the following C# interface in one project...

```
//C#
namespace FunctionalInterfacing  
{  
    public interface IFoo  
    {  
        string Bar(string a, string b);  
    }  
}
```

and now i want to write a type in  F# that implemented that..

```
#light
module FunctionalInterfacing.Concrete
open FunctionalInterfacing

type public ConcreteType = 
    interface IFoo with
        member this.Bar a b = a
```

which doesn't seem to work, im getting the following error...

> This override takes a different number of arguments to the corresponding abstract member

any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your override shouldn't be in curried form (where the arguments are separated by spaces).  Try

```
member this.Bar(a,b) = a
```

instead.